# Programming camera for ROI selection

Tags: image-processing, opencv, camera

I want to transfer an ROI instead of the full Image using Camera. This I am doing to increase the (usefull) data transfer rate from camera to PC(less data, less time), where I will be doing some Image processing on the ROI. Basically the user will define the ROI's coordinates, using which the camera will capture ROI and will send ***only*** this ROI to the PC through USB or gigaBitEthernet.

Is it possioble to do this programatically since my application will need  ROI which will be changing dynamically.  Do we have some APIs that lets us define ROI and prgram the camera accordingly?

I will be using C/C++ with OpenCV for the entire application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we have some APIs that lets us define ROI and prgram the camera
>   accordingly?

This all depends on your camera and the driver. Some cameras produced by [Point Grey](http://www.ptgrey.com) have this feature and they come with a SDK that provides an API for setting a ROI.